# Softraid 5 Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, raid, raid5

I have installed a raid 5 on my ubuntu server 14.04 and I want to know how I replace a hard disk and make it recover/build on that HDD.

My setup is 4 1tb hard disk in raid 5. No other HDD's or SSD's everything will run on the raid 5 HDD's

Answer (score 0):

assuming your raid device is `/dev/md127` (check the `md` number, by doing `cat /proc/mdstat`), you can do:

```
 mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdf5
```

with `f5` being the proper partition (or use just the drive letter if you put the whole drive in the raid).

You can add a new partition of the right size at any time, so you can try this out before hand, it just does get added as spare if the raid-5 is not degraded (yet).